# Post to a user wall and post comments

Tags: php, joomla, jomsocial

I am using mobile application (html, jQuery, php) to interact with JomSocial and I have been able to post to groups, discussions and more. The way I do this is look at the controller through the url and go to the actual controller class e.g. `/controllers/groups.php` and see how it's implemented. So when I see `www.mysite.com/groups/1`, I know the controller is `groups.php`

The problem am having is that user's profile is not like this. The url looks like

```
www.mysite.com/1200-victor-gee-fred/profile
```

I assumed this would be profile.php but nothing like posting to a wall in that class.

**Question**: What controller is handling the display of user profile? If you also know how I can post on a profile wall and post reply/comment to it, I will appreciate this.

> I know these tables are involved: **_users**, **_wall**, **_actvities** etc. But
>   the sequence of saving into those tables is what I don't want to miss
>   and have been successful with other entities except user's profile
>   wall.

Comment: The .htaccess file (if you're using Apache) should shed some light on this. Can you post it?

Comment: @nickb which portion do you want to see?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the Joomla tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody might need this in future, I finally found the controller.

```
components/com_community/controllers/system.php
```

These functions were used

- `public function ajaxStreamAdd($message, $attachment)` - goes into jom_community_activities table
  where `$message` is the text entered in the "Share" box and `$attachment` is a JSON-encoded string that contains the target, actor, access-level, app etc
- `public function ajaxStreamAddComment($actid, $comment)` - goes into jom_community_wall table
  where $actid is the userid of the user posting the $comment

Best Regards